# How do i get the 'branch' icon to display in TFS 2013 Source Control when using the TFS API?

Tags: branch, tfs-sdk

While experimenting with the TFS 2013 API, I ran into the following issue which I can't seem to resolve when programmatically creating a new branch like this:

```
//var workspace = connect-to-tfs-server-and-locate-workspace

workspace.PendBranch(scmSourcePath, scmTargetPath, VersionSpec.Latest);
changes = workspace.GetPendingChanges();
workspace.CheckIn(changes, "I just create a branch");
```

or even via,

```
workspace.CreateBranch(scmSourcePath, scmTargetPath);
```

The branch is created just fine, however the new icon featured here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181425.aspx is not displayed (notice the alternative icon in the image at FeatureTeamA). Instead the 'uninformative' folder icon is shown.

If i create the same branch using the Source Control Explorer it does show the new 'branch icon'. Anybody any ideas what I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to convert the parent folder to `BrancObject` if it isn't one yet:

```
// The source of the branch must first be created as a branch object 
VersionControl.CreateBranchObject(new BranchProperties(new ItemIdentifier(sourceServerPath)));

// Then you can create the branch 
VersionControl.CreateBranch(sourceServerPath, targetServerPath, VersionSpec.Latest, null, checkinComment, null, null, null);
```

See also:

- http://geekswithblogs.net/TimH/archive/2012/04/19/programmatically-create-a-branch-with-the-tfs-2010-api.aspx

Comment: Well, that wasn't obvious at all. Much appreciated :)